# How to setup SSL for Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate, ad-certificate-services

I have a Windows 2008 Server (Base2) machine.

*In Server Manager > Roles, i can see:*
1. Active Directory Domain Services
2. DNS Server
3. Active Directory Certificate Services.

Under Active Directory Certificate Services > mydomain > Issued Certificates , i see a certificate listed. If i 'open' this Certificate its purpose is listed as 'Private Key Archival'

*I want to get my Active Directory working in SSL (port 636).*

When i use ldp.exe (a ldap client), to connect to port 636 with SSL checkbox enabled, i get an error ('Cannot Open Connection'), this works fine for default 389 port.

I am new to Windows Server Administration/Certificates.
**What else do i need to setup?**

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to get your DCs to support BIND via LDAPS.  To do this, you will need to add a certificate to your domain controllers' Personal Certificate Store that meets the following requirements.  This certificate could either be from a locally housed Certificate Authority or a Third-Party Authority.

- The LDAPS certificate is located in the Local Computer's Personal
  certificate store (programmatically known as the computer's MY
  certificate store).
- A private key that matches the certificate is present in the Local Computer's store and is correctly associated with the certificate.
- The private key must not have strong private key protection enabled.
- The Enhanced Key Usage extension includes the Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1) object identifier (also known as OID).
- The Active Directory fully qualified domain name of the domain controller (for example, DC01.DOMAIN.COM) must appear in one of the following places: The Common Name (CN) in the Subject field. DNS entry in the Subject Alternative Name extension.
- The certificate was issued by a CA that the domain controller and the LDAPS clients trust. Trust is established by configuring the clients and the server to trust the root CA to which the issuing CA chains.
- You must use the Schannel cryptographic service provider (CSP) to
  generate the key.

The above was taken from KB321051: [How to enable LDAP over SSL with a third-party certification authority](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051).

Additional information on how to setup a local CA for using LDAPS can be found at the following article: [LDAP over SSL (LDAPS) Certificate](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2980.ldap-over-ssl-ldaps-certificate.aspx)

Once your DCs have the proper certificate installed, LDAPS communication should automatically be enabled.  You can verify this with `ldp.exe` as you were attempting to do.

Comment: I know this is resurrecting a long-dead question, but can you explain how one would go about using "the Schannel cryptographic service provider" to generate a private key?